# How to compare the value of the current for-each element?

Tags: xml, xslt

XML:

```
<a>1</a>
<a>2</a>
<b>3</b>
<a>4</a>
<b>5</b>
```

Desired output:

```
value a
value a
value b
value a    
value b
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each select="a | b">
  <xsl:if test="? = 'a'"> 
    value a
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="? = 'b'">
    value b
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

How to compare the value of the current element in line `<xsl:if test="? = 'a'">` and `<xsl:if test="? = 'b'">`?

Comment: I think if you change your condition to `<xsl:if test="name(.) = 'a'"> ` it might work. I don't have a tool available to test that right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `name()`, but this is a strange way of going about it. From what you posted, you just want to output the names of nodes. In this case:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select='a|b' />

<xsl:template match='a|b'>
    value <xsl:value-of select='name()' />
</xsl:template>
```